# Firefox Shader Editor not working when I modify the shaders in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, opengl-es, webgl

I am trying to run WebGL on firefox , it works fine if I modify them externally , but doesn't work if I load them in firefox shader editor.

To get a shader editor , you could right click on firefox browser ->inspect element and then check shader editor to see the GLSL code. But modifying them should modify the experience which is currently not working for me , any suggestions?

I am looking for a solution like [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjM9_znrKfNAhVLt48KHXzHA5cQtwIIMTAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DhnoKqFuJhu0&usg=AFQjCNHcd29kRSfvJm3eBgkGu8wkEywF8g&bvm=bv.124272578,d.c2I) ,where on editing it will reflect the canvas automatically .

Comment: Which version of firefox? is it firefox-dev?

Comment: downloaded developer's version but still not working :(

Comment: Can you provide a test page to checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the problem is that Shader Editor doesn't redraw anything for you, just recompiles shaders and relinks a program. You should continuously redraw everything with `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
function render () {
    /* do actual drawing */
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();
```